# Differential equation, general solution by substitution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation: $$(x^2+xy)\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2$$

i must find the particular solution satisfying the extra condition $y=1$ when $x=2$

so i used the method of substitution and i ended up with $$x\frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{v}{v+1}$$ do i proceed with variable seperation now and integrate both sides?

Comment: what is $\nu{}$?

Comment: i substituted $y=vx$

Answer (score 2):

If you substituted $y=vx$ in the differential equation, you get
$$\left(\frac{1}{v^2}+\frac{1}{v}\right)\left(v+x\frac{dv}{dx}\right)=1$$
$$x\frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{v}{v+1}$$
As you have stated already.

Now you need to go for variable separation.
$$\frac{v+1}{v}dv=-\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$(1+\frac{1}{v})dv=-\frac{dx}{x}$$
Integrating, you get
$$v+\ln v=-\ln x + c$$
$$\frac{y}{x}+\ln \frac{y}{x}=-\ln x + c$$

Hope this helps you.

Comment: And here, again, Lambert function $y=x\,W(\frac c x)$